# How to set manually the UINavigationController's root in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

A logged-in user will see a list of items and the relative detail view after tapping them.

After the login, the server tells me how many items the list would have. If it would contain only one item, I should skip the list view and see just the detail.

Currently my Interface Builder is set as:

```
Login → (segue) → [NavigationController] → List → (push) → Detail →...
```

But if there's only one item, the root of the Navigation Controller should become the Detail Controller:

```
Login → (segue) → [NavigationController] → Detail →...
```

So I need to change the Navigation Controller's `viewControllers` property. In the login view, I can access the Navigation Controller when preparing the segue:

```
// Login View controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if itemsCount == 1 {
    let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
    let detailController = DetailViewController()
    navController.setViewControllers([detailController], animated: false)
  }
}
```

I can't make it work as expected: when I run the code, it displays the Detail View, but all the `@IBOutlet`s I've set in it have a `nil` value.

Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` function to create `detailViewController`, rather than rely on the plain initialiser `DetailViewController()`.  The latter just creates a new instance of the class, while the former reads in the VC details from the storyboard and sets all the outlets etc.